# Is it possible to configure RollingFileAppender tor maintain no more than 2 files?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

So I use `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender` I want to keep logs only from today and yesterday. Is it possible with log4net RollingFileAppender to keep not more than only 2 log files (remove old)?

Answer (score 1):

you can set [MaxSizeRollBackups](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups.html)

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
       ...
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
   <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
</appender>
```

But only if you are not using date/time boundaries:

From log4net [RollingFileAppender class documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html):

> A maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time boundaries
>   is not supported.